Identify an old movie about analyzing a dream
I took an "intro to electronic music" class in university, and we watched several films that demonstrated the evolution of electronic music in cinema. I am trying to remember one of them we watched.
I believe it was black-and-white, and had something to do with analyzing someone's dream. They are trying to figure out a mystery by analyzing what someone is dreaming. I believe it was a bit of a mystery movie, a bit psychological. The only image I remember in the movie was in the dream there was a house-like building, and on the roof was a maybe a deformed wheel and it was supposed to represent a gun. I think.
And because of the context in which I watched it, I assume it has a remarkable soundtrack for some reason or another.
I hope this is enough to go on. I really don't remember any more than that.

Reading this question made me think of Dreamscape even though it was in the 80s.

'Eternal sunshine of the spotless mind' comes up here... However it's a 90's/2000's movie in colour.

I think this is Spellbound, 1945 by Alfred Hitchcock. The dream sequence was by Salvador Dali. If I recall it has your wheel representing a gun. Can't remember the soundtrack.

I agree, 'Wheel as gun' is either Spellbound or somebody quoting Spellbound. It's a famous sequence.
